# How to write ElementTree to a file object in Python?

Tags: python, lxml

I have a XML-file that I need to send to some URL. I do that this way:

```
data = { 'file' : open('test.xml', 'rb') }
req = requests.post(URL, files=data)
```

This works, but problem is that first I need to generate XML, then I need to do this:

```
et = etree.ElementTree(root)
et.write('test.xml', encoding='utf8')
```

and then after that I do this:

```
data = { 'file' : open('test.xml', 'rb') }
req = requests.post(URL, files=data)
```

But I don't like this, I have XML-file, then I write it to disk, just to read it again from disk.

Is there a way to write that XML directly to file object (equivalent of `open('test.xml', 'rb')`) without writing it to file first?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tostring`

**Ex:**

```
et = etree.ElementTree(root)
req = requests.post(URL, data=etree.tostring(et.getroot()))
```